# Is there any courses or tutorials for Appium Automation?

Tags: automated-testing, appium

I was wondering if anyone here know some courses or tutorials to set up and start to use Appium, I want to use it on my Mac to do automation tests on iOS and Android.

I have already looked at the official Website of Appium but I am a bit confused and lost to set everything up. So if you know anything that could help me that would be wonderful!

Comment: Have you read this? http://appium.io/getting-started.html?lang=ru

Comment: Yes and I feel their website really confusing, from a page to another there are different instructions for the same idea and so at the end I have the impression to go in the wrong direction.

Comment: Is there any exact place that confuses you?

Comment: Sounds stupid but in this sentence:
Run npm install. When running npm install, make sure to be on Xcode 8+

What do they mean on Xcode 8+?

Comment: npm is Node.js packet manager (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm), XCode is a set of dev tools for developers which code for apple products (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). I think it is better to start from looking up the terms otherwise neither of existing tutorials would be effective.

Comment: I know what are node and Xcode is not really the problem is just how the sentence is written " make sure to be on Xcode 8+"

Comment: Is it possible to use Appium on Mac to do automation tests on Android as well?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some reference links where you can learn Appium from Basics, required steps in installation, Working with Android native devices & iOS devices.

1. [Toolsqa](http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-tutorial/)
2. [Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-appium.html)
3. [Appium_for_Android_and_iOS](http://appium.io/tutorial.html?lang=en)
4. [Softwaretestinghelp](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/appium-tutorial-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get fair understanding on appium, check out [robot framework library.](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html)
It provides inbuilt keywords to interact with ios/android operating system.